# Auto populate table from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to populate a table with data from another worksheet based on result on Vlookup.

Sheet1 Range("receiptNum") has a number data that will be searched from Sheet4("transcTable") and when I run the Sub it actually found the "matched number" however it continue to write data all the way down to destination table. Also what code do I need to add to handle error if No data found?

Here's my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim intItems As Integer
Dim cellx As Range, rowX As Range
Set rowX = Sheet1.Range("A12")


Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  ws.Unprotect
 Next ws


 Range("date").Value = Application.VLookup(Range("receiptNum"), Range("transcTable"), 2, False) 'Date
 Range("name").Value = Application.VLookup(Range("receiptNum"), Range("transcTable"), 3, False) 'Name


 intItems = 0
 For Each cellx In Range("receiptNumRec")
  CellXRow = CellXRow + 1
  If Range("receiptNum").Value > "" Then
   intItems = intItems + 1
    rowX.Offset(intItems - 1, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(Range("receiptNum"), Range("transcTable"), 1, False)
     If rowX.Offset(intItems - 1, 1).Value > "" Then
      rowX.Offset(intItems - 1).Value = intItems 'Item Num
     End If


  End If
 Next cellx


 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  ws.Protect , DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
 Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: the line `rowX.Offset(intItems, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(Range("receiptNum"), Range("transcTable"), 1, False)` would look up the value in *Range("receiptNum")* repeatedly and return the same result each time. If you expect different results then you should look up differing values.

Comment: Actually, sometimes there are multiple rows of data with the corresponding receiptNum to look for also there are other data in the columns but I want to start writing code for one column to check if its working, Apologies, I forgot to mention it on my post.

Comment: Your question gives no clue as to what you would like the output to look like. Anyway, you shouldn't expect a result from a loop you didn't build. Therefore the next step is to build that missing loop into your code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, for the time being I will try the first loop to work (any help would be appreciated) before writing another one, obviously I'm a newby to VBA environment that's why I asking

Comment: When you build nesting loops it's often easier to build the inside before the outside one. Since you already built the outside loop you can cut it short by placing an *Exit For* just before the *Next* so that you can concentrate your testing on the inside loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is to use ListObjects.Range.AdvancedFilter then loop vlookup on extracted table, I know it's a complicated code but at least it works. AdvancedFilter is a great function only if source and destination table is identical in format & number of columns.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, numX
numX = Application.VLookup(Range("receiptNum"), Sheet4.Range("transcTable"), 1, False)

If Not IsError(numX) Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  ws.Unprotect
 Next ws
 
  With Sheet4
    If Sheet1.Cells(8, 6) <> "" Then
      .Cells(1, 10).CurrentRegion.ClearContents
      .Cells(1, 19) = .Cells(1).Value
      .Cells(2, 19) = Sheet1.Cells(8, 6)
      .ListObjects(1).Range.AdvancedFilter 2, .Range("S1:S2"), .Cells(1, 10)
    End If
  End With
 Range("pickSlipClear,contactDetails").ClearContents
 Call transcSearch 'run Search function
 Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Select
    
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  ws.Protect , DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
 Next ws
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 
Else
 MsgBox "Receipt Number doesn't exist!"
 Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Select
 
End If
End Sub

Sub transcSearch()
Dim i As Integer
Dim lng As Long
Dim xcell As Range, rowX As Range
Set rowX = Sheet1.Cells(12, 1)

 Range("date").Value = Application.VLookup(Range("receiptNum"), Sheet4.Range("transcTable"), 2, False) 'Date
 Range("name").Value = Application.VLookup(Range("receiptNum"), Sheet4.Range("transcTable"), 3, False) 'Name
   i = 0
   lng = 0
   For Each xcell In Range("prodX")
    i = i + 1
    lng = lng + 1
    If xcell.Value > "" Then
      rowX.Offset(lng - 1).Value = i 'Item Num
      rowX.Offset(lng - 1, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(xcell.Value, Sheet4.Range("filterX"), 2, False) 'Type
      rowX.Offset(lng - 1, 2).Value = Application.VLookup(xcell.Value, Sheet4.Range("filterX"), 1, False) 'Description
      rowX.Offset(lng - 1, 3).Value = Application.VLookup(xcell.Value, Sheet4.Range("filterX"), 3, False) 'Qty
      rowX.Offset(lng - 1, 4).Value = Application.VLookup(xcell.Value, Sheet4.Range("filterX"), 4, False) 'Unit
      rowX.Offset(lng - 1, 7).formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(dataTable[ON-HAND],MATCH(@desc,dataTable[Product Description],0)),0)" ' Available stock
      rowX.Offset(lng - 1, 8).formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(dataTable[Supplier],MATCH(@desc,dataTable[Product Description],0)),0)" 'Stock cost price
    End If
   Next xcell
End Sub
```